# Zoom to layer extent in Openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, if-statement, openlayers-3

I have a drop down list of application numbers and when the user clicks on one of these, I would like my application to display that feature on the map from my application layer and then zoom to its extent.

The feature is displaying correctly but I cannot seem to be able to zoom to the extent of the layer, I receive an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

The relevant code is below which is within an if statement, there appears to be some sort of issue with the last 2 lines - is it because I am unable to call methods to the map layer as it was created at the same time? Do I need to delay the zoom to extent somehow?

```
if (name === "planning") {
      var planapp = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.TileWMS({url: '../../geoserver/wms',
      serverType: 'geoserver',
      params:{
        'LAYERS':"planning:planapps_testlayer", 'TILED':true, 'cql_filter':"applicatio='" + datum.APPLICATION_NUMBER + "'"
      }
      }),
      name: 'planapp',
      label: 'Planning Applications',
      visible: true
      });
    map.addLayer(planapp);
    var selectedAppExtent = planapp.getExtent();
    map.getView().fit(selectedAppExtent, map.getSize());
  }
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Use your browser Developer Tool (F12) to put a break point on the last line of that piece of code to see what's going on.  For further debugging, you can use `ol-debug.js` and step into the code to see what's going on and see where the error in the stack trace.  HTH.

Comment: I tried this suggestion, it appears as though selectedAppExtent is returning undefined, so it cannot retrieve the extent for the planapp layer for some reason.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/ol3-dev/getextent/ol3-dev/EHfJtLECeZ0/pZ0hte16Lz4J and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/how-to-get-wms-layers-extent-openlayers3

Comment: Does this mean the getExtent function does not work with TileWMS source layers?

Comment: @Chris, IBAW but were you able to fix this, I'm having the exact same problem, thanx